# Drawing 1D CNN architecture

Tags: deep-learning, graphs

How can I draw CNN Architecture like this one here:

[image]

Comment: This picture is too small, I can't see the intermediate labels.

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a python script over here: https://github.com/gwding/draw_convnet

I hope it's helpful